# powershell get the bigger disk freespace

Tags: powershell, drive

I can get all my logical drives  and the corresponding freespace with this script:

```
$elements = get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk
$array=@()

foreach ( $drive in $elements ) {
    $freespace = $drive.freespace / (1024*1024*1024)
    $freespace = [math]::round($freespace, 1) 

    $name=$drive.Name
    $d=New-Object PSObject

    $d | Add-Member -Name Drive -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $name
    $d | Add-Member -Name Free_Space -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $freespace 

    $array+=$d

 }
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to manipulate my `$array` to return the name of the drive with the bigger freespace, with `measure -Maximum` for example

Comment: Bigger? Relative (percentage) and absolute (bytes)?

Comment: Um, `$Array|Sort Free_Space|Select -Last 1` doesn't work for you? Or are you looking for largest % of drive space free?

Comment: hello Mathias,it does not return the drive with the largest freespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$LogicalDisks = get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk

$MostSpace = 0
$MostName = "None"

foreach ( $drive in $LogicalDisks ) {

$FreeSpace = $drive.FreeSpace / (1024*1024*1024)

$FreeSpace = [math]::round($FreeSpace, 1)

if ($FreeSpace -gt $MostSpace) {
  $MostSpace = $FreeSpace
  $MostName = $Drive.Name
  }

}

Write-Host $MostName
```

It'll put the drive letter into $MostName and then you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Welcome.  Also, technically you could probably get rid of the two lines where we're converting from bytes to GB as well.